# What is the function of __builtin_va_start in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When tracing [kthread_create_on_node](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.21/source/kernel/kthread.c#L503), I encountered va_list, va_start, and va_end, but I don't understand the purpose of [__builtin_va_list](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.21/source/include/linux/stdarg.h#L5), [__builtin_va_start](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.21/source/include/linux/stdarg.h#L6), and [__builtin_va_end](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.21/source/include/linux/stdarg.h#L7). Also, who is responsible for implementing them? Thank you.

Comment: Nothing specific to the linux kernel. These are just the compiler's builtins (GCC or Clang) that are used to provide [`va_arg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg) functionality.